# Mass importing bookmarks into Adobe Acrobat PDF

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, adobe-acrobat

I have a large scanned PDF file which I want to make easier to navigate via adding a list of bookmarks.

I have created a simple list of bookmark titles and page numbers in notepad like so:

```
Title Page 1
Section 1 12
Section 2 23
Section 2.2 25
etc.
```

Is there any way to do this in Adobe Acrobat or via some free plugin? I can't seem to figure it out and doing it manually will take ages